# kwicks slider loading but mouse hover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added kwicks javascript , css , jquery but the slider is not working

I tested the website in firebug and it's not showing any error or undefined variable

http://demo2.inheritedarts.com/george/

can some one help me finding a bug ? is it in my code or something i am doing wrong

Comment: where you initializing your `kwicks `

Comment: Check header now it was inside 1 js i have put in header now

Comment: now its working, i can see they are expanding. on which browser you are testing?

Comment: I can see its working on Firefox now but not in chrome

Comment: working perfect on chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this script in your `<head></head>` tag

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.kwicks').kwicks({
                    maxSize : 250,
                    behavior: 'menu'
                });
            });
        </script>
```

i think you forgot to initialize your `ul` element with `kwicks` API

Comment: but its not in page you shared